# random dataframe - sum and average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a random dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I am trying to run this 10 times. In order to create a dataframe which is the sum of the 10 random dataframes before dividing it by 10 to find the average.

Comment: You do know that the statistics of the final dataframe will be the same that of each individual one right?

Comment: would it not re-run to produce a fresh number each time

Comment: That fresh number will be just as random as one produced by averaging 10 r.v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is create list of DataFrame, join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and create `mean` per first level:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD')) 
       for x in range(10)]

df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(10)).mean(level=0)
print (df)
       A      B      C      D
0  50.96  50.05  53.74  54.56
1  55.38  46.49  53.57  46.51
2  50.53  48.29  45.57  47.64
3  49.69  51.70  55.11  48.40
4  52.57  50.28  53.17  47.20
5  50.49  48.60  48.29  50.49
6  45.26  54.60  47.78  46.62
7  50.92  48.27  56.30  47.28
8  47.57  46.51  52.90  46.07
9  45.54  49.72  49.38  45.71
```

Or create `DataFrame` with 10 times more rows, create `MultiIndex` and again get `mean`:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100 * 10, 4)), 
                  columns=list('ABCD'), 
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(10), range(100)]))
df = df.mean(level=0)
print (df)
       A      B      C      D
0  50.96  50.05  53.74  54.56
1  55.38  46.49  53.57  46.51
2  50.53  48.29  45.57  47.64
3  49.69  51.70  55.11  48.40
4  52.57  50.28  53.17  47.20
5  50.49  48.60  48.29  50.49
6  45.26  54.60  47.78  46.62
7  50.92  48.27  56.30  47.28
8  47.57  46.51  52.90  46.07
9  45.54  49.72  49.38  45.71
```

Comment: great thanks. I removed the keys label as it wasn't quite adding as i wanted but works well. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that accepts n - number of times you want to run this operation.

```
def func(n):
    df_total = 0
    for i in range(n):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
        # to add similar dataframes just use + operator
        df_total = df_total + df
    return df_total / n
```